# c# uwp client server connection send string

Tags: c#, tcp, server, uwp, client

I have a problem with 2 uwp apps : one client and one server to communicate.

I have a textbox and a button on each.

The server side is like this :

```
listenerSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
IPEndPoint ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8888);
listenerSocket.NoDelay = true;
listenerSocket.Bind(ipEnd);
listenerSocket.Listen(0);
```

and on ButtonClick

```
Socket clientSocket = listenerSocket.Accept();
Byte[] Buffer = new byte[clientSocket.SendBufferSize];
int readByte = clientSocket.Receive(Buffer);
txtEvents.Text = readByte.ToString();
```

On the client side is like this

```
client= new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
IPEndPoint ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8888);
```

and on buttonClick_Event

```
client.Connect(ipEnd);
client.Send(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hey");
```

But nothing is happen.
Thanks for your help
best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [document Note](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/sockets) part:

> As a consequence of [network isolation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh770532.aspx), Windows disallows
>   establishing a socket connection (Sockets or WinSock) between two UWP
>   apps running on the same machine; whether that's via the local
>   loopback address (127.0.0.0), or by explicitly specifying the local IP
>   address.

You can try to test your socket on two devices which deploy the client and server respectively.

Besides, you can also enable loopback for network access and troubleshoot network isolation issues, please see the [How to enable loopback and troubleshoot network isolation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780593.aspx) topic to get details.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i try on separate devices and that's run.     But now i have an other problem with this line Socket clientSocket = listenerSocket.Accept();    i want to do it without to click on the button. to start my app and to do that. Is it possible ? thanks for your help

Comment: In uwp,  the [page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page) have some events will trigger when your app runs, such as the [Loaded](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.loaded), it will occur when a page has been constructed and added to the object tree, and is ready for interaction. You can also add the code in the [Page.OnNavigatedTo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.onnavigatedto) method, it will 
 be invoked when the Page is loaded and becomes the current source of a parent Frame

Comment: Of course, it bases on your requirement, you also have the choice to put it in the App's constructor or the `OnLaunched` method or the Page's constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I try to modify my code with this sample : 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3f4d435b-48c8-4b5f-9c5c-8ba1166fd808/uwpctcp-socket-server-using-ipendpoint-uwp?forum=wpdevelop
That's help me with the Accept(); hangs on my app but now on my server side i try to see the text send by client with this line

```
private void RecieveArg_Completed(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] recBuf = new byte[e.BytesTransferred];
        Array.Copy(buffer, recBuf, e.BytesTransferred);
        string ReceivedText = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recBuf);
        txt_Events.Text = ReceivedText;
        Client_Socket.ReceiveAsync(RecieveArg);
    }
```

but nothing appear on my server txt_Events box. I know that the client is connecting because the server is closing.
Thanks for your help.